# Django how to not use cached queryset while iterating?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset which I iterate through in a loop. I use data from the queryset to change data inside the queryset which might be needed in a lter step of the loop.

Now the queryset is only loaded once at the beginning of the loop. How can I make django reload the data in every iteration?

Comment: It looks like you are headed in a direction which could cause a lot of performance issues. what is your exact use case ?

Comment: An admin action, which iterates through a number of sporting matches and recalculates current standings from scratch regarding the leaderboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload each object in the start of the loop body. Just use TheModel.objects.get(pk=curr_instance.pk) to do this.